# How to solve ESLint's "prefer default export" error when exporting a variable?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

In my separate `validation.js` file I export a variable called `noFutureDate`:

```
export const noFutureDate = value => {
  const userDate = value.split('-').join('');
  ...
  return userDate < now;
};
```

Then in my component I import `noFutureDate` like so:

```
import { noFutureDate } from '@/validation';
```

But ESlint annoyingly says:

> error: Prefer default export (import/prefer-default-export) at
>   src/validation.js:1:1:

I know how to use `export default` with functions and such, but what to do here with my variable `noFutureDate`, how can I export it while keeping ESLint happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see the `/` slash in a rule, that rule doesn't come from ESLint proper.

`import/prefer-default-export` is a rule that comes from `eslint-import-plugin` (which you may have directly imported, or some config you are using in your environment has imported it).

The docs for this rule at https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-default-export.md make no special mention of why this rule is suggested; some rules are purely for stylistic reasons (and indeed the same plugin lets you enforce the opposite: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-default-export.md ). The named imports has more rationales in favor of using it that I have seen--such as that it can be flexible to add to the exports in the future.

So while normally many eslint rules (or rules set by plugins) have good justifications, others can be safely ignored. Unless a vue-specific plugin is recommending it for some reason related to that environment (I don't know vue.js myself), I think you can safely ignore this.

There are different ways to ignore rules in eslint. You can disable with an [inline comment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments), for just a [group of files](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-only-for-a-group-of-files) within an `.eslintrc.*` file, or you could just disable the rule [for your whole project](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules).

However, if you did want to change your code rather than ignore, or find it is advised for a reason, you can do:

```
export default value => {
  const userDate = value.split('-').join('');
  // ...
  return userDate < now;
};
```

and in the other file:

```
import noFutureDate from '@/validation';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const noFutureDate = value => {
  const userDate = value.split('-').join('');
  ...
  return userDate < now;
};

export default noFutureDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export default { noFutureDate }
```

Comment: Welcome, Yoki. Please take a moment to review the accepted answer. It's a good example of the level of explanation that's useful to provide on Stack Overflow. Keep in mind that our goal is to help future readers learn, not simply to provide answers. Given that, can you edit your answer to offer more explanation? It would also be useful to discuss how it compares to the accepted answer.

Comment: As simple as efficient.

Comment: @YokiYu LOL. You are lucky to just stayed at zero points with your "simple as efficient" retort. I remember getting negative score without giving me a chance to correct myself, that I ended up deleting my answer.

Comment: @duduwe Hah~ that's true. I would love to write down a tons of explanation but in this case, simple answer gives the clearer understandability.